# Expectation of a recursive random variable with multipart definition.

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $Y_{t}$ be the random variable with $Y_{t}$=
\begin{array}{ll}
X_{t} \in \mathbb{R} & \mbox{ with probability }  p\\
\alpha Y_{t-1} & \mbox{ with probability } 1-p
\end{array}

$\alpha,p \in (0,1)$. The $P(X \leq x)$ is known.
I'm trying to find the $E[Y_{t}]$. Thanks!

Comment: Are you simply looking for an expression? That is quite simple if you apply the definition of expectation.

Comment: Thank you for your response. You mean that, if $Y_{1} = X_{1}$ with probability $p$ starting at $t=1$, then $E[Y_{1}] = pE[X]$ and thus, recursively, $E[Y_{t}] =pE[X] + (1-p)E[Y_{t-1}]$. Is this correnct?

Comment: Not actually. It should be $E[Y_t]=pX_t+(1-p) \alpha Y(t-1)$. I think you are missing some initial conditions for $Y_{t-1}$. Can you cross check please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, $E[Y_t]=pE[X_t]+(1-p)\alpha E[Y_{t-1}]$. If every $E[X_t]$ and the starting value $E[Y_0]$ are known, this yields
$$
E[Y_t]=(1-p)^t\alpha^t E[Y_0]+\sum_{k=1}^tp(1-p)^{t-k}\alpha^{t-k}E[X_k].
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response! That is, $E[Y_{t}]$ depends on $t$ even if $E[Y_{0}]$ and $E[X_{k}]$ are consts.

Comment: Should there be p^k in the second term?

Comment: @hotchpotch No.